# How to Update form radio button

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have a problem with updating a form that is consists of questions with type radio button to answer it, I had tried a lot but it doesn't change anything in the database when I choose new buttons.

For submitting I used

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
      {

  $v1 = intval($_POST['v1']);
  $v2 = intval($_POST['v2']);
  $v3 = intval($_POST['v3']);
  $v4 = intval($_POST['v4']);
  $v5 = intval($_POST['v5']);
  $v6 = intval($_POST['v6']);
  $v7 = intval($_POST['v7']);
  $v8 = intval($_POST['v8']);
  $total = $v1 + $v2 + $v3 + $v4 + $v5 + $v6 + $v7 + $v8 ;
  $Percentage = $total / 32 * 10 ;


 mysql_query("UPDATE grades_presentation SET P1='$v1',P2='$v2',P3='$v3',P4='$v4',P5='$v5',P6='$v6',P7='$v7',P8='$v8',TOTAL='$total',Percentage='$Percentage' WHERE SID='$id' ") or die(mysql_error());
 header("Location: mark.php");
```

And this is one of the questions, I have used Checked to give me which button user have checked!

```
<tr>
<th bgcolor='FF6600'> Clarity of speaking
(Could you hear the speaker properly and clearly?)<font size="4" > </font></th>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "4" <?php echo ($v1=='4')?'checked':'' ?>   onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "3" <?php echo ($v1=='3')?'checked':'' ?>  onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "2" <?php echo ($v1=='2')?'checked':'' ?>  onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "1" <?php echo ($v1=='1')?'checked':'' ?>  onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>    
</tr>
```

Comment: In HTML, all radio button name is set to `v1`, is that typo?

Comment: @MuthuKumaran, `Radio buttons` uses same name because only one from a group become submitted.

Comment: no not all v1! , first one is v1 , second v2 ..etc + no values had changed in the database even the first one!

Comment: Try `echo` the SQL statement `echo "UPDATE grades_presentation SET P1='$v1',P2='$v2',P3='$v3',P4='$v4',P5='$v5',P6='$v6',P7='$v7',P8='$v8',TOTAL='$total',Percentage='$Percentage' WHERE SID='$id' ";` and check in on your phpmyadmin.

Comment: are you getting the post values?Is your echo-ed query have those values?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is value="X" is never updated, only the state of the radio is.